# How to import csv file with some required fields missing

Tags: import

I am running CiviCRM v.4.7.6. I am trying to import a csv file into contacts. Some of the members of the organization do not have email accounts and as a result the import rejects those records. Is there any way to import a file that has some of the required fields missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Email address isn't a required field unless you don't also have a last name.  At present, CiviCRM requires either a last name or an email address, but not both.

Comment: Ok, I interpreted the error I got incorrectly. Looking at the csv file of rejected records (all 5 of the test records) I see this line: "Invalid value for field(s) : Addressee must be one of the configured format options. Check Administer >> System Settings >> Option Groups >> Addressee for valid values".  Checking the format for valid options shows this: "{contact.individual_prefix}{ } {contact.first_name}{ }{contact.middle_name}{ }{contact.last_name}{ }{contact.individual_suffix}". Each of the records I am importing has a name, an address, a city, and a zip code. What could my error be?

Comment: You are right. My mistake was accidentally matching the street address in the import file with the "Addressee" field. When I corrected that the import went without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many contacts you have that don't have emails, a short-term work-around would be to:

1. Put into the CSV a blatantly false email address for each contact (example: example@example.org)
2. Import the contacts
3. Search for the email address you used, and
4. Use the Batch Update action (with a profile that has email address) to
   remove all of the fake email addresses at once.

This will remove the email address from each person, but still keep the contact records.